# How to create appium node executable with xcuitest and uiautomator2 driver?

Tags: node.js, npm, appium, node-modules, npm-package

I've followed this tutorial https://testsigma.com/blog/executable-file-for-appium-server/ and  created appium node executable and it's working. I can copy this exe file in any other machine where node not installed and it still it works.

The issue here is, xcuitest and uiautomator2 drivers are not added in the executable file. I tried by saving the drivers also similar way how i did for appium but not working. And tried many ways but nothing worked.

**Question here is :** Any way to bundle the drivers also along with the appium into the node executable so that when I run the exe file it starts the appium server and initializes the drivers as well (Expecting this to work in the machine where nodejs not installed..)?